# value 0 everywhere in my column table

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

Controller :

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Profits.ToList());
        }

public ActionResult Create(Profits profits)
{
    {
        var user = db.UserProfiles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserId == WebSecurity.CurrentUserId);
        var category = db.Categories.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Id == profits.CategoryID);
        var profit = new Profits
        {
            Value = profits.Value,
            Description = profits.Description,
            DateInput = profits.DateInput,
            CategoryName = category,
            User = user
        };
        db.Profits.Add(profit);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

index.cshtml:

```
model IEnumerable<WebHFM.Models.Profits>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CategoryID)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Value)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateInput)
        </td>
```

In MSSQL Server I see the right info. Table profit with column named `=CategoryName_id` has the right data (1 or 2 or whatever is my primary key of table `Categories`) but in my index view where I should see `Name` (Categories model) I see only Number 0 everywhere.

Basically in my `View` I want to see a HTML table with column names from `Profits` Model:
  `Categories`, `value` , `description`, `dataInput`

Comment: Include your Index() controller method (public ActionResult Index(){}) please. What you have included is the Create() controller method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller, you might need:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(db.Profits.Include("Categories").ToList());
}
```

In your view, you will need:

```
model IEnumerable<WebHFM.Models.Profits>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CategoryName.Name)
        </td>
    </tr>
```

The reason you are seing zeros, is because where you had this line:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CategoryID)
```

CategoryID isn't a property in your database, it is a property in your model, so when you pull from the database, this property doesn't get updated with a value. The default for an int is 0, so you get zeros. Even if you did populate this value, you'd just have numbers everywhere, not the categoryname. This:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CategoryName.Name)
```

will fix your problem by getting the actually categoryname from your object.

The confusion is you've named your property Profits.CategoryName when it should be Profits.Category or something to indicate that it's not actually a string but an object.

Lastly, you may or may not need the Include(), it just depends on when your dbcontext is being disposed, but probably you will need it. I have it currently as `Include("Categories")` but I'm not sure what the name of your navigation property actually is, it could be something different. If it's not "Categories" and I had to guess, I'd guess at `Include("CategoryName1")`

Comment: Incredible patience Mike . Very helpful when I get some reputation in stackOverFlow I will vote for your 2 solution .Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Your lambda expression is the problem.  Try some basic HTML in your foreach first:

```
    <td>
        @item.CategoryID
    </td>
```